# Retrieving data out of XML by key, clarification needed

Tags: java, xml

Given a string:

```
<APP START="2014-08-25 13:45:58" SINCE="2014-08-25 13:45:58" STATE="Running" NAME="abc" ID="4305" Codebase="www.domain.com" Build-Revision="3d6ca1de3ce6d9832bc314356e54038bb8cab342" Build-Path="UNKNOWN" Build-Label="128.3" Build-Date="2014-08-16 20:03:34" Permissions="all-permissions">
<Runtime NUM_PROCESSORS="12" TOTAL_MEMORY="8588886016" MAX_MEMORY="8588886016" FREE_MEMORY="4902842840"/>
</APP>
```

How can I request for the value of, say, `Build-Label`?

Comment: Please provide attempt.

Comment: What does your current code look like, and what specific issues are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    private static String XML = "<APP START='2014-08-25 13:45:58' SINCE='2014-08-25 13:45:58' STATE='Running' NAME='abc' ID='4305' Codebase='www.domain.com' Build-Revision='3d6ca1de3ce6d9832bc314356e54038bb8cab342' Build-Path='UNKNOWN' Build-Label='128.3' Build-Date='2014-08-16 20:03:34' Permissions='all-permissions'><Runtime NUM_PROCESSORS='12' TOTAL_MEMORY='8588886016' MAX_MEMORY='8588886016' FREE_MEMORY='4902842840'/></APP>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        InputSource xml = new InputSource(new StringReader(XML));
        String result = (String) xpath.evaluate("//@Build-Label", xml, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I always try to use JAXB to marshall XML code, then I just can simply access the property value.